# Characterization of weak Lebesgue spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would be interested to know whether the following is true:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbf{R}^n$. Let $g$ be a nonnegative function $g : \Omega \to \mathbf{R}$. If there is a constant $C > 0$ such that
\begin{equation} \frac{1}{|A|^{1-1/p}} \int_A g \leq C \end{equation}
for all measurable subset $A \subset \Omega$, then $g$ is in weak-$L^p(\Omega)$.

If the above inequality holds only for open balls in $\Omega$, is $g$ still in weak-$L^p(\Omega)$ ?

Edit: I changed the question to make it more relevant and less naive. Most comments below are out of date.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Basically the question is whether weak `$L_p$` and `$L_p$` are the same. The answer is probably in your text book.

Comment: @Bill : this is a question I was asking myself

Comment: There's very simple counterexamples, such as $g(x)=1_{\{\max(\vert x_1\vert,\ldots,\vert x_{n-1}\vert)\le1\}}$, which works for any $n(1-1/p)\ge1$.

Comment: @George : Thanks but your $g$ is bounded. I changed the topic so as to avoid such a counterexample. In fact, even ending up in $L^p_{loc}$ would be interesting for me.

Comment: Doesn't $g(x)=x^{-1/p}$ on $(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ give a counterexample?

Comment: ...and also $g(x)=\Vert x\Vert^{-n/p}$ on $B_1(0)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Of course you mean $p>1$.  For $p=1$ what you wrote is equivalent to $g$ being in `$L_1$`.

Comment: For the updated question, $g(x)=(x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n-1}^2)^{-\frac np}$ looks like it gives a counterexample for any $n(1-1/p) > 1$.

Comment: @Bill: yes. I mean $p > 1$. Although my question is trivially true for $p=1$ :)

Comment: @Georges: I think your counterexample does not lie in weak-$L^p$, but in weak-$L^{p(n-1)/n}$. Because
$$ \{t : g(t) > \alpha\} = B^{n-1}(0,\alpha^{-p/n}) \times \mathbb{\R}$$.
Let's say the domain is in fact bounded in the $x_n$ direction, thus the measure of $\{t : g(t) > \alpha\}$ is $C \alpha^{-p(n-1)/n}$.

Comment: The answer is no for $p>1$. Consider a function distributed like `$x^{-1/p}$` on $[0,t]$ for small $t$, and add together translates of this function so that the distance between the supports of the functions are big with respect to $t$.

Comment: @unknown (google): No, it is not in weak $L^p$, but that is the point. It still satisfies the inequality for open balls.

Comment: @George: sorry, it was late in Europe... 

Comment: Moving targets can be difficult to hit...

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Yemon, and I vote to close.  The idea behind MO is not to have the questioner continually edit the question while comments list counter-examples to previous versions of the question.